# Length of the string is different after converting from base64

Tags: c#, ruby

I have a string which is generated using `C#` `Convert.ToBase64String`

But after decoding the same string using ruby `base64.decode`, length of the string is different, what could be the issue.

`C#` encoded string:

```
dABlAHMAdAA=
```

ruby code

```
name=decrypt(ARGV[0])
puts "#{name.to_s}"
puts "#{name.to_s.length}"

def decrypt(input)
  return Base64.decode64(input)
end
```

ruby check_login.rb

```
dABlAHMAdAA=
test
8
```

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: C# encoded string : dABlAHMAdAA= (test)

Comment: `Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"));` returns me `"dGVzdA=="`

Comment: to decode the string provided `String result = Ecoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("dABlAHMAdAA="));` Note `Unicode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> dABlAHMAdAA= (test)

This looks like base64-encoded UTF-16.

> dGVzdA==

Seems to be base64-encoded UTF-8 (which, for an ASCII-string like "test" is simply ASCII, since that's a subset of UTF-8 - but not of UTF-16).

So the original characters were encoded in different schemes, and then the actual bytes were base64-encoded.

Comment: how do we convert the same, i am using a windows machine C# to encrypt and solaris box ruby to decrypt

Comment: You will have to pick a representation (ascii, UTF8, UTF16) and use it on both sides and appropriately convert the encoding before doing the Base64 encode step (or after the Base64 decode step, depending)

Answer (score 0):

To *decode* the String provided by Ruby (so we're adapting *C#* to *Ruby*)

```
  String source = "dABlAHMAdAA=";
  // test
  String result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(source));
```

To encode (so that Ruby can read it)

```
  String source = "test";
  // dABlAHMAdAA=
  String result = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(source));
```

In both cases note `Encoding.Unicode` which stands fro UTF-16

Answer (score 0):

Hack that works for ASCII:

```
Base64.decode64('dABlAHMAdAA=').delete "\u0000"
#⇒ "test"
```